# "Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation" in SSIS Package

Tags: ssis

I am getting below error in SSIS package while doing the mapping with destination table.

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202040
Error at Target etl [vw_Fact_PartnerDeal [194]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x8007000E.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x8007000E  Description: "Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation."

Can someone please suggest on this.

[image]